# UNIQUE inserts with primary key and clustering column using IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: cassandra

I'm new to Cassandra.  Given I want to be able to sort by account_id, how would unique inserts work?

E.g.

INSERT INTO test (email, active, account_id, password, name, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) IF NOT EXISTS

I would have assumed that if the email already existed in the database I would have received an "applied false".  However, if the email exists and the account_id is different I'm finding another row is inserted into the database.

How would one execute a LWT using IF NOT EXISTS when there is a primary key and a clustering column.  I only want the insert to apply only if the primary key doesnt exist.  I don't want the logic to include the primary key + clustering column.

```
CREATE TABLE test.testing (
    email text,
    account_id uuid,
    password text,
    name frozen <name>,
    active boolean,
    phone map<text, frozen <phone>>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((email), account_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the use cases you have mentioned in the post is you want only one row for each email id .

If this is what you want then you have to remove the account_id from the primary key .

So then the email will be only partition_key in your schema .

Cassandra does not support sorting on non clustering column so to sort query by account_id you can either user spark on top of this or you can do sorting on your backend .

Comment: This makes sense.  To be clear if you're using a clustering column that becomes part of the primary key.